# ReactNative Navigation to other screen from a button click, while other route is not defined in Tabbed navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-navigation

I am using `react-navigation` module and have defined following screens routes:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './src/ScreenDashboard';
import TodosScreen from './src/ScreenTodos';
import ContactsScreen from './src/ScreenContacts';

                            // Defining navigation (using tabbed navigation style)
const AppWithNavigation = TabNavigator(    
{                                         
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    Todos: { screen: TodosScreen },
    Contacts: { screen: ContactsScreen }
},
{
 ...
}
```

If I try to add transition to any other screen I will have to do it via:

```
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;   // child component reading navigation from its props
<Button onPress={ () => navigate('Todos') } />
```

But the issue is, I do not want to make transition to my **Todos** component screen, I have another component **Appointments**, I want to do transition to that component. How can I achieve that? As if I include its route in `TabNavigator()`, that will start displaying additional tab in my navigation (which I don't want to show).

Same logic applies when I want to do screen navigation upon clicking **add, edit, search** buttons. Those can not be defined in navigation routes (so to make them visible in main navigation). I hope you understood my problem.

In web ReactJS we simply define routes, which is pretty good, but don't know how to manage those stuff here.

[image: app main screen]

Basically I want to switch screen when I click any of the strip on my main screen.

[image: The bottom tab navigation is working]

Comment: My demo code: https://gist.github.com/mhannan/c5ce5df86b7962c3505be8f5141793a8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest navigators inside other navigators. In your case, inside TabNaivgator you can insert StackNavigator

```
const TodoNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Todos: { screen: TodosScreen },
    Appointments: { screen: AppointmentsScreen},
    // other screens
})

const AppWithNavigation = TabNavigator(    
{                                         
    Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
    TodosTab: TodoNavigator,
    Contacts: { screen: ContactsScreen }
}
```

Now, when you press Todo tab, it will open your todo screen, because by default, first screen is loaded. To navigate to AppointmentsScreen, you need to call `this.props.navigation.navigate('Appointments')` and it will transition to that screen. And you still will be in Todos tab (it will be active). If you want you can hide tabs and do bunch of different things, take a look at documentations.

You can learn more about nesting navigators [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting)

Comment: I have updated my question. I don't understand why I need to add `StackNavigator` when I don't want to have stack navigation (correct me if my understanding is wrong about it). I just want to trigger a navigation, such that when I click any strip / card on main screen, or click on Add or Edit button (available in my inner any of screen), it trigger my screen navigation and render relevant component/ view.

Comment: To my understanding, the `StackNavigation` is a visible stacked list of options, that user can click on to navigate between screens. I don't know how that will fit in our usual screen layouts and buttons.

Comment: The Add button is somewhere in our screen design layout and Edit or search button are somewhere else in our screen layouts (generally speaking). So, to my opinion that is from no where StackNavigation. Don't know if my understanding is correct in ReactNative navigation system.

Comment: so, if i understand correctly, you want to navigate user to completely new screen (show different screen) when you press some buttons/cards (add, edit etc). In order to navigate between screens, you will need a navigator, basic of them being StackNavigator. 
It seems, your understanding of StackNavigator is something similar to TabsNavigator, where buttons will be shown in some part of screen, one on top of another. This is not the case. StachNavigator won't show any buttons anywhere, it is similar to your routes in react

Comment: Stack in the name of StackNavigator refers to the way navigation is handled, where every time you go to new screen it is 'piled' on top of previous screen, not visual placement of buttons on device

Comment: I tried your solution, but when I add Stack navigation inside my Tab navigation, another tab starts appearing. I have seen doc. but didn't find any option related to hide any particular tab.

Comment: can you post your navigators, TabNavigator and StackNavigators in your question?

Comment: I have added the demo code link in the Question comments.

Comment: Followed your provided core guidelines, and found this reference which assisted me to resolve my problem. Three things assisted me to resolved the issue. 
**1).** Your guidelines 
**2).** This article and its video: https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-react-navigation-the-navigation-solution-for-react-native-ea3f4bd786a4 
**3).** And ofcourse then it lead me to understand the documentation correctly: 
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/nesting
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options#Navigation-Option-Reference

also played with `navigationOptions`.